# Unknown usage of dwLength and SsHandle members in PEB_LDR_DATA

Tags: windows

I've been implementing some Windows internals code and when I have tried to document this structure I have not been able to do so because of those two members. I can't find anything about them.

This is the definition of the structure I'm talking about:

```
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {
    DWORD      dwLength;
    DWORD      dwInitialized;
    LPVOID     lpSsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
    LPVOID     lpEntryInProgress;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```

Does anyone know its actual use or content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know length is sizeof(struct)

```
0:000> ?? sizeof(ntdll!_PEB_LDR_DATA)
unsigned int64 0x58
0:000> dt -r nt!_peb Ldr->Length @$peb
ntdll!_PEB
   +0x018 Ldr         :
      +0x000 Length      : 0x58
0:000>
```

edit

[As per Geoff Chappel there is No known Usage of SSHandle](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/inc/api/ntpsapi_x/peb_ldr_data.htm)
so just leave it as PVOID

Comment: I will leave it as a mystery. Thanks!

Comment: if you found the answer was sufficient enough for the purpose mark it as such so that it doesnt popup in unanswered queue

Comment: `SsHandle` certainly _sounds_ like "subsystem handle" ... so given the (ex-Win32, now) Windows subsystem (csrss) is the only proper subsystem left in modern NT versions (WSL isn't such a subsystem), there's a chance that this played a role when NT still had a  POSIX and OS/2 "personality", too ... but just guessing. At least registration with csrss is one of the big items during Win32 UM process initialization.